# How to remove duplication of flow logic?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a service/manager class where I fetch users from data source. The methods are simulare in flow but has different retrieve methods.

```
    public User GetByUserName(string userName)
    {
        user = dependencyResolver.UserRepository.GetByUserName(userName);

        if (user == null) return null;

        AddStuffToUser();

        return user;
    }

    public User GetById(int id)
    {
        user = dependencyResolver.UserRepository.GetById(id);

        if (user == null) return null;

        AddStuffToUser();

        return user;
    }

    public User GetByUserName(string userName, string encryptedPassword)
    {
        user = dependencyResolver.UserRepository.GetByUsernameAndPassword(userName, encryptedPassword);

        if (user == null) return null;

        AddStuffToUser();

        return user;
    }
```

I would like to remove the duplication of the flow logic, but I can't find a satisfying design. I could do it by using OOP but I think that adds to much complexity for such a simple task. I also tried passing the fetch methods as a `Func<>` parameter, but I didn't get it right since the fetch methods have different parameters.

Which are my options here?

Comment: I've read till the line: `user = dependencyResolver.UserRepository.GetByUserName(userName);` where you're breaking law of demeter. Fix it first

Comment: Interesting remark @AlmaDo. `dependencyReslover` only returns repository interfaces. I could have written `IUserRepository userRepository = dependencyResolver.UserRepository; userRepository.GetByUserName(userName);` The `dependencyResolver` is passed to the constructor of the service. I understand I shouldn't trust a friend of a friend, but `dependencyResolver` and `UserRepository` are more like brothers than friends. Can I trust a brother to a friend or is this still breaking Law of demeter?

Comment: I believe what you're trying to do is encapsulate a [Cross-Cutting Concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern). Be aware that you're actually moving outside the realm of OOP and into AOP at this point.

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
if (user == null) return null;

        AddStuffToUser();

        return user;
```

with:

```
return doXYZ(user);
```

and add:

```
private User doXYZ(User user){
    if (user != null){
        AddStuffToUser();
        return user;}
    return null;
```

at this point u placed 6 Lines for 9 and its better code-style (OOP-standard is usefull in any task)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The example in the question is simple and can - as you suggest - be refactored. But I'm looking for a more general solution for when you want to remove duplication of flow logic.